# Not getting response in paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I have tried this code but I didn't get response

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="fm">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="GBP" />

    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test_biz@email.com" />

    <?php
        for($m=0;$m<4;$m++){
    ?>

        <input type="hidden" name="quantity_<?php echo $m+1; ?>" value="1" />   
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $m+1; ?>" value="<?php echo "fhghg"; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $m+1; ?>" value="<?php echo 10; ?>" />

    <?php
        }
    ?> 


    <input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/test/test1.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/test/test.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost/test/test.php">
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

I have `echo` the array as `print_r($_POST)` to print the response. It displayed as `Array()`

How to solve this?how to pass the variable to paypal for multiple items ?

Comment: Are you sure the queries on port 80 are redirected to your computer and that no firewall is blocking the communication?

Comment: enable `php_openssl` extension on your localhost.

Comment: php_openssl doesn't matter, however you SHOULD be using mod_ssl on Apache and submitting https urls. Opening port 80 is step two, posting to a url that's online is more important

Comment: @ClosetGeek - *I think* it does matter to get response. Paypal will redirect to localhost using `https` and that requires openssl as per i used before and got some problems getting response. :-/

Comment: php_openssl is an extension for using openssl functions in PHP scripts, such as key signing. Openssl libs are needed for using ssl streams/sockets in scripts, but doesn't always require php_openssl ext(streams don't, sockets do). But for receiving https on a server (unless the server is a PHP deamon) he will need mod_ssl for Apache or the equivalent for his given server. Paypay will *redirect the browser* to localhost which works if he is on the computer with the server running on localhost. 'notify_url' however is used for IPN type services, requiring a server with access 'from the internet.

Comment: @Pankit Kapadia - To be specific, 'return' and 'cancel_return' are used for redirecting the shoppers browser. 'notify_url' is used by paypal for posting information *from* paypal over a secured connection to the server. php_openssl requirement is based on how you handle the IPN event. php_curl I believe requires php_openssl, as so does php_sockets. php streams does not, they just need the openssl libs which are installed in most situations, where php_openssl is not, and php_curl and php_sockets often aren't available either.

Comment: @user1859340 - Variables are posted using multiple means. You need to clarify your question a little more. For example, are you trying to use the variables for posting an order (such as with an IPN script) or are you just trying to make a thankyou page (such as when they are redirected back to your site)

Answer (score 0):

The superglobal `$_POST` is always an array. If you only get `Array()` in the output for `print_r($_POST)`, this means nothing was posted, and the array is empty (just be sure you're using `print_r()` and not `print()` here.

If you don't want to print the whole array, but instead print individual fields' values from this array, use keys such as `$_POST['item_id']`, which prints the value of the `item_id` key in `$_POST`.

Comment: how to post the variables can You explain in coding in php?

Answer (score 0):

Is test1.php a Paypal IPN script? Paypal can't access localhost to post order notices to it (the 'notify' field). This has to be an actual URL. If your testing at home try a dynamic ip service like no-ip.com.